# Compare 2 similar files and only output the differences, preserving the order in which they occur?

Tags: sed, diff, comm

hoping someone can help me get my head around this

I have 2 files, one is 325 lines long, one is 361 lines long.

The bulk of these files is identical content but the 2nd one has random extra lines inserted. I am only interested in the extra lines, and I need to preserve the order in which they occur in the file.

The files contain a repeating paragraph of approximately 31 lines - I know the first and last line of this paragraph, and have no problems with dropping the entire paragraph, but can't work out how.

i.e. File1

```
The quick brown
fox jumped 
over the
lazy dog
The quick brown
fox jumped
over the
lazy dog
The quick brown
fox jumped
over the
lazy dog
```

i.e. File2

```
The quick brown
fox jumped
over the
lazy dog
sadhasdgh
qyyutrytkdaslksad
utyiuiytiuyo
The quick brown
fox jumped
over the
lazy dog
djakdjhgmv
asdjkljkgfyiyi
The quick brown
fox jumped
over the
lazy dog
jghytpuptou
```

I need to output only the extra lines in this order:

```
sadhasdgh
qyyutrytkdaslksad
utyiuiytiuyo
djakdjhgmv
asdjkljkgfyiyi
jghytpuptou
```

Any help or advice would be gratefully received, I am not a *nix person unfortunately :(
I tried a few diff expressions and comm expressions, but can't get what I need.

Answer (score 3):

Try this magic command:

```
diff file1.txt file2.txt | sed -n 's/^> \(.*\)/\1/p'
```

`diff file1.txt file2.txt` should output something like

```
2c2
< fox jumped 
---
> fox jumped
4a5,7
> sadhasdgh
> qyyutrytkdaslksad
> utyiuiytiuyo
8a12,13
> djakdjhgmv
> asdjkljkgfyiyi
12a18
> jghytpuptou
```

`sed -n 's/^> \(.*\)/\1/p'` should find lines staring with `>` and output that lines without `>`. Possible reason why this doesn't work is different output of diff at your system?

Comment: Couldn't get this to work, but thanks anyway - got no output when I tried even on the files above.

Comment: Worked out why it didn't work for me, it's because my diff commands adds + and -, not < and > for differences - many thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

This should work -

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]++;next} !($0 in a){print $0}' file1 file2
```

**Explaination:**

`NR` and `FNR` are `awk's built-in variables`. `NR` registers the number of records and does not get reset to `0` when working with two files. `FNR` is similar to `NR` but gets reset to `0` after the file is completely parsed through.

In this `awk` one-liner, we keep that condition `NR==FNR` which is to force action `{a[$0]++;next}` only on the file1 (as `NR==FNR` will only be true till we are working with `file1`). This action stores each line in an `array`. `next` is added so that the `second action` does not get called upon. Once this `NR==FNR` becomes `untrue`, the `first action` is never called. `awk` moves to the `second action` which is to check the content of the `file2` with respect to the `array` (i.e `file1`). If the content of `file2` is in the `array`, we ignore it. If it is not there in the array we print it as those lines would be the ones that are **extra** and only in `file2`.

**Test:**

*File1:*

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat file1
The quick brown
fox jumped 
over the
lazy dog
The quick brown
fox jumped
over the
lazy dog
The quick brown
fox jumped
over the
lazy dog
```

*File2:*

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat file2
The quick brown
fox jumped
over the
lazy dog
sadhasdgh
qyyutrytkdaslksad
utyiuiytiuyo
The quick brown
fox jumped
over the
lazy dog
djakdjhgmv
asdjkljkgfyiyi
The quick brown
fox jumped
over the
lazy dog
jghytpuptou
```

**Execution:**

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]++;next} !($0 in a){print $0}' file1 file2
sadhasdgh
qyyutrytkdaslksad
utyiuiytiuyo
djakdjhgmv
asdjkljkgfyiyi
jghytpuptou
```

Comment: Wow, that is superb - just what I was after, thanks so much. Now I have to read and try and understand why it works!!!

Comment: I added some explanation. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU diff):

```
diff -bu file1 file2 | sed -n '1,2d;s/^+//p'
sadhasdgh
qyyutrytkdaslksad
utyiuiytiuyo
djakdjhgmv
asdjkljkgfyiyi
jghytpuptou
```

Answer (score 0):

```
diff -b sample.log sample.log.1 | awk '/>/ {print $2}'
```